# Do apps using multiple processes share a Dalvik instance?

Tags: android, process, dalvik

I'm studying Android process management and I'm wondering whether apps using multiple processes (not threads) share a Dalvik instance or there exists a Dalvik instance per process, even for the same app.

Could you point me to some official source (**doc, talk, paper** etc.)?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No.  Dalvik doesn't span processes.

However, the Binder IPC mechanism can do a very convincing job of making objects appear to migrate to a different process and its Dalvik instance.  Also, the memory management is very good about sharing read-only pages across all processes that need them.  The Dalvik process hosting a typical app is forked off of zygote with all the common android libraries already mapped, so new unique copies don't have to be opened.

Comment: I'm an official source, and I approve this message. :-)