# Understanding Android

Tags: dalvik

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding Android: Zygote and DalvikVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153166/understanding-android-zygote-and-dalvikvm)

I am trying to understand how Android launches applications. The question is how does zygote exactly fork Dalvik VM. I don't really understand why it is not possible to run multiple applications in the same Dalvik VM.

Comment: have you  checked http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29

Comment: yes of course. I have checked a lot but didnt find a good explanation about low level functionalities in android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried: https://sites.google.com/site/io/dalvik-vm-internals? There are a couple slides on Zygote.

Additionally, the link to the video is: http://youtu.be/ptjedOZEXPM, and the Zygote section is discussed at 13:43.

I hope this helps. (This would be better as a comment, but I don't have the reputation yet)

Answer (score 2):

Strangely, this is an exact duplicate of your own question [Understanding Android: Zygote and DalvikVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153166/understanding-android-zygote-and-dalvikvm/12703292#12703292). Anyone looking for the answer, please check my answer there.