# where .apk file is placed in phone after installation

Tags: android, location, apk

I have following questions

1. Please explain about the installation procedure for android app.
2. What is the temporary folder location for .apk files,when we install an android app?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

APK is copied to /data/app of root. Data related to apk is generated in /data/data/app_name

You could have got enough articles on this on StackExchange after searching, for example:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5147/the-installation-steps-of-android-package

[Android: Understanding the APK installation process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12442979/android-understanding-the-apk-installation-process)

Comment: Hi and thanks rahul, this link (and figure) explain very well the details of building the apk, BUT it does not explain the details of the APK installation process, it only states for both running on an emulator and a device "...and install your apk on the device (emulator)..." I still need to understand what Anroid OS modifications occurr during an apk installation, which so far in the awesome thread, remains unanswered, please assist.

Comment: hi i am also looking for the .apk files i have downloaded. I don't see the apk in system>app , here are just samsung and android apk's. I check with ddms and monitor/ddms. Which folder holds the downloaded apk's? thanks

Comment: /data`/`data/app_name

Answer (score 2):

Preinstalled applications are in

> /system/app

folder. User installed applications are in /data/app. I guess you can't access unless you have a rooted phone. I don't have a non rooted phone here but try this code out:

```
public class Testing extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "TEST";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        File appsDir = new File("/data/app");

        String[] files = appsDir.list();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < files.length ; i++ ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "File: "+files[i]);

        }
    }
```

see this video too to learn the work flow of .apk file installation

https://sites.google.com/site/io/inside-the-android-application-framework

Answer (score 0):

System apps are located under director :

```
 /device/system/app
```