# "How are" Android applications (Facebook etc.) installed to an android phone?

Tags: java, android, apk, android-package-managers, android-install-apk

I know how to install an application to an `Android` device e.g from *Play-Store* or via an *.apk* file. But I'd like to understand the actual process of installation.

E.g. on Windows:

- Serial codes etc. are placed in the registry
- Files important to the running of software are placed within the *Program Files* folder (*the main `.exe` etc.*)

So far, what I do know about the `Android` application installation process is:

- After an android application has been executed (post-installation), data freshly downloaded is placed in locations like: *Android/data* or *Android/obb* etc.
- If specifically expressed by an Android developer, files can also be placed elsewhere e.g. on *secondary storage* (memory cards, cloud storage etc.)

But other than that, my knowledge concerning the Android installation process is pretty slim e.g.:

- I don't know where important files relating to an Android program's execution are placed (in the case of Windows, the *.exe*, related media, libraries etc.)
- I similarly don't know how these files are structured upon an Android device (post-installation) e.g. are these files structured in folders like: *java*, *res*, *menu*, *layout* etc. as during development within environments like Android Studio?
- Neither do I know how what application file-types are stored on a user's device post-installation (after being unpacked from the android installation file or *apk*) e.g. are they stored as *.java* and or *.xml* files, as during development etc.

Hopefully someone can fill in the blanks, thank you.

Comment: One thing you can be sure of: there is no one general answer. Especially now after the switch from Dalvik to ART. Have you ever considered rooting a device and just looking what you'll find?

Comment: You don't need to root a device to take a look around. Plug a phone into your computer and run `adb shell`. The commands are similar to a unix shell - e.g. you can type `cd` and `ls`. Check out directories like `/data/app`. http://blog.shvetsov.com/2013/02/access-android-app-data-without-root.html

Comment: Beyond finding a description of the APK format at your favorite wiki - the newer stuff about ART was covered at the last Google IO: https://youtu.be/EBlTzQsUoOw

Answer (score 13, accepted):

***Beginnning***

PackageInstaller calls InstallAppProgress activity to receives an instruction from the user. InstallAppProgress will ask `PackageManager` Service to install package via installd. Source code is available at `<Android Source>/packages/apps/PackageInstaller`.

When we install `APK` file, Package Manager parse the package(`APK`) file and display confirmation, When user press OK button, Package Manager call method named `installPackage` with these four parameters namely `uri`, `installFlags`, observer, `installPackageName`. Package Manager start one service named "package", now all fuzzy things happen in this service. you can check `PackageInstallerActivity.java` and `InstallAppProgress.java` in PackageInstaller source code. Package Manager Service running in system_service process and  install daemon (installd) that runs as a native process both start at system boot time.

***Where `APK` files stores in `Android` ?***

1. Pre-Install (i.e. Camera, Calendar, Browser,etc.) `APK` stored in /system/app/
2. User Install (ApiDemo, Any.do, etc.) APK stored in `/data/app/`
3. Package Manager create data directory `/data/data/<package name>/`  to store database, shared preference, native library and cache data

You might see `apk` file and `*.odex` file for same `APK`, `ODEX` file is totally different discussion and purpose.

***What is APK installation process in detail ?***

Following process execute in `Package Manager Service`.

- Waiting
- Add a package to the queue for the installation process
- Determine the appropriate location of the package installation
- Determine installation Install / Update new
- A copy of the apk file to a given directory
- Determine the UID of the app
- Request to installd daemon process
- Create the application directory and set permissions
- Extraction of dex code to the cache directory
- To reflect and packages.list `/system/data/packages.xml` the latest status
- Broadcast to the system along with the name of the effect of the installation is complete package 
  `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED`: If the new ( `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED`): the case of an update.

[image]

***How Package Manager store data ?***

Package Manager store application information in three files, located in  `/data/system`. Following sample is extracted from `Android 4 ICS` emulator image.

**`packages.xml`**:This file contain list of permissions and Packages/Applications. 
This `xml` file stores two things 1. permissions 2. package (application), permission are store under `<permissions>` tag. Each Permission has three attributes namely name, package and protection. Name attribute has permission name which we are using in `AndroidManifest.xml`, package attribute indicate permission belong to package, In majority cases "android" is values because `<permission>` tag contain default permissions and protection indicate level of security.

**`packages.list`**: It is simple text file contain package name, user id, flag and data directory, I can't find any perfect description but I assume it that `packages.list` file may provide faster lookup of installed package because it file keep important information only.

```
com.android.launcher 10013 0 /data/data/com.android.launcher
com.android.quicksearchbox 10033 0 /data/data/com.android.quicksearchbox
com.android.contacts 10001 0 /data/data/com.android.contacts
com.android.inputmethod.latin 10006 0 /data/data/com.android.inputmethod.latin
```

**`packages-stoped.xml`**: This file contain package list which has stopped state, Stope stated applications can not receive any broadcast.

***Where I can find the source code of Package Manager and Package Installer ?***

**Package Manager**

```
frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/pm/Settings.java
frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java
frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/pm/IPackageManager.aidl
frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageSignatures.java
frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/pm/PreferredActivity.java
frameworks/services/java/com/android/server/PreferredComponent.java
frameworks/core/java/android/content/IntentFilter.java
frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java
frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/pm/Installer.java
frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/app/IMediaContainerService.aidl
frameworks/base/packages/DefaultContainerService/src/com/android/defcontainer/DefaultContainerService.java
```

**Package Installer**

```
packages/apps/PackageInstaller/src/com/android/packageinstaller/PackageInstallerActivity.java
packages/apps/PackageInstaller/src/com/android/packageinstaller/PackageUtil.java
packages/apps/PackageInstaller/src/com/android/packageinstaller/InstallAppProgress.java.
```

***Links to refer***: [link 1](http://kpbird.blogspot.com/2012/10/in-depth-android-package-manager-and.html) and [link 2](http://java.dzone.com/articles/depth-android-package-manager).

Comment: How does the android O.S extract .dex files and where does it extract them to, for each installed application?

Comment: OS retrieve package from apk, so it store it in `/data/system`. please refer to my answer's titles *What is APK installation process in detail* and *How Package Manager store data*. There is everything described in details.

Comment: I meant, how does the Android O.S "extract dex code to cache directories" and where are these cache directories located for each application?

Comment: ah, sorry. So, since `apk` is sort of archive, so it convert `apk` to `zip` and simply extract files. This is the example of the path `/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.hfad.bitsandpizzas@base.apk@classes.dex`. Found one more link, could be useful.href="https://github.com/dogriffiths/HeadFirstAndroid/wiki/How-Android-Apps-are-Built-and-Run

Comment: What I mean is, I know how to extract the apk file: so I can see "AndroidManifest.xml", "classes.dex" and "resources.arsc" etc. But you mentioned above, that after the O.S extracts the apk, it then extracts classes.dex to a cache location: where is this location? and how does it extract the classes.dex file to show the original classes?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean... if you want to convert `dex` to java source by yourself, so you use [dex2jar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar) , path is the same as in my comment above `/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@yourpackagename@base.apk@classes.dex` and OS doesn't convert `dex` file to original. It is specially converted to `dex` that `Dalvik VM` can execute them... About `Manifest` I didn't check and cannot find any relevant link, but I guess it must be on same path. Just check it yourself. Maybe you need a root for this, but cannot say for sure.