# Installation process of .apk within ART. Difference from Dalvik VM installation process

Tags: android, apk, dalvik, android-package-managers, android-install-apk

Recently I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358687/how-are-android-applications-facebook-etc-installed-to-an-android-phone), where was described whole installation process of `.apk` file to android phone. The one thing it was about using `Dalvik VM`. And now I'm wondered is installation process is exactly same using `ART`? What are the differences?
I mean the work of *PackageManager*, *path*, *convertion to `dex` format* etc.
Googling didn't give much info, only about performance power, managing memory and something similar.
I would be very thankful if someone with knowledge could share this information.

Comment: There's not much difference for art, other than it runs dex2oat to generate an art file, rather than dexopt to generate an odex file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Android apps come in the `.apk` file format, with Java classes converted into `DEX` bytecode. The `DEX` bytecode format is independent of device architecture and needs to be translated to native machine code to run on the device. This is the same for both the `ART` and the `Dalvik` runtimes.

The most significant change from `Dalvik` to `ART` is that `Dalvik` is based on ***Just-in-Time*** (`JIT`) compilation, while `ART` is based on ***Ahead-of-Time*** (`AOT`) compilation.

With the *Dalvik JIT compiler*, each time when the app is run, it dynamically translates a part of the `Dalvik` bytecode into machine code. As the execution progresses, more bytecode is compiled and cached. On the other hand, ART is equipped with an Ahead-of-Time compiler. During the app’s installation phase, it statically translates the `DEX` bytecode into machine code and stores in the device’s storage. This is a one-time event which happens when the app is installed on the device.

***Performance***

The most important benefit of `ART` runtime over `Dalvik` runtime is that the app runs faster on `ART`.  Because `DEX` bytecode has been translated into machine code during installation, no extra time is needed to compile it during the runtime. The app starts faster as well when launched with `ART` for the same reason.

Because `Dalvik` requires extra memory for `JIT` code cache, an app occupies a smaller memory footprint when it runs on `ART`.

***Battery Life***

With `Dalvi`k runtime, the `JIT` compilation is `CPU` bound. Because of `AOT` compilation, `ART` frees the CPU from translating `DEX` bytecode to machine code during the app’s execution, thus reducing energy consumption. Using `ART` leads to a longer battery life, which is the time interval when a battery recharging is needed.

***Installation Time***

Because the `AOT` compiler translates `DEX` bytecode into machine code during the app installation, an app takes longer to install on a device with `ART` runtime. Considering the benefits of faster execution and shorter launch time we discussed in the previous section, this extra time which happens only once during the app’s installation is well worth it.

***Storage Footprint***

With `ART` runtime, the `AOT` compiler translates the app’s `DEX` bytecode into machine code and stores it in the device’s storage. The pre-compiled binary occupies more space than the DEX bytecode. Thus results in a larger storage footprint comparing with `Dalvik` runtime.

***Summary***

To this point we have introduced the new `ART` runtime for Android. We also discussed its benefits and compromises, centralizing in its Ahead-of-Time compilation and performance improvement.  Currently released for preview and still under active development and optimization, at this point of time we cannot provide a quantitative conclusion on how much performance gained by switching to `ART Runtime`. One thing for sure is ART will replace `Dalvik` as the Android runtime on the `x86` based devices.

[Source](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/06/18/art-vs-dalvik-introducing-the-new-android-x86-runtime).

Comment: In which path does the ELF files are stored?

Answer (score 0):

In dvm architecture, at each time when the application  launches the entire application byte code converted into dex and then execute the dex files. So when at each Time of launch same thing going to done, so to overcome this problem ART comes into picture. In ART while at the time of application installation only converts byte to Dex and then  at every launch execute that same dex files, here no need to require conversion at each launch., so less time take to launch an app in ART compare to dvm.