# Where is Android App Code stored?

Tags: android

Once a .apk file has been installed, where is the extracted dex code stored, to be precise, what subdirectory of data/data/appname/...? And, is it actually stored as dex code or is it converted to something else for storage?

Answer (score 1):

APK is copied to /data/app of root. Data related to apk is generated in to /datadata/app_name

related post

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5147/the-installation-steps-of-android-package

[Android: Understanding the APK installation process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12442979/android-understanding-the-apk-installation-process)

Comment: Yes, I know that, thank you, but where exactly is the executable code stored? In what subdirectory of /data/data/appname...