# Rename Base.apk

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

I need to know about **base.apk**. When i run the following code:

```
PackageInfo paramPackageInfo = null;
try {
    paramPackageInfo = MainActivity.this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(MainActivity.this.getPackageName(), 0);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
ApplicationInfo localApplicationInfo = paramPackageInfo.applicationInfo;
```

String str2 = localApplicationInfo.sourceDir;

The value in Marshamallow of str2  is:

```
/data/app/com.package.name-RY_AUYdNAwLZg==/base.apk
```

and In kitkat it is:

`/data/app/com.package.name.apk`

Now i want to know how can i rename this base.apk to my application name or are there any changes in manifest or gradle for that? The installed apk which is displayed on home screen of both the devices have correct names then why in Marshmallow in only directory it is named as base.apk

Comment: 1) Why??? --- 2) calling `applicationInfo` will crash your application if your previous code goes into the catch part