# ::Android Framework:: Which is first runner, zygote or dalvik?

Tags: java, android, frameworks, dalvik, init

I have a question involving the Android framework.

Every boot sequence shown on the Internet or in books shows the flow starting from zygote to dalvik as follows.

[image: Android Boot Sequence Image]

However, according to my code research, init processor runs `app_process(app_main.cpp)` before loading zygote like this :

```
[init.rc] : 

service zygote **/system/bin/app_process** -Xzygote /system/bin --zygote --start-system-server
```

Because `zygote(ZygoteInit.java)` is java file(a kind of class), it needs the dalvik virtual machine to be executed so `app_process(app_main.cpp)` initializes dalvik machine and makes it ready for start.

And then loads `ZygoteInit.java` via dalvik.

Thus, zygote actually run.

It seems to me that the process which initializes and loads dalvik is not zygote but app_process and zygote is under dalvik because it is composed of java code.

**The only thing that makes me doubt this is some code in app_main.cpp.**

Watching `main` function in `app_main.cpp` file, you can find some lines as below :

```
[app_main.cpp] :

       if (niceName && *niceName) {

            setArgv0(argv0, niceName);

            **set_process_name(niceName);**

       }
```

`niceName` is pointing to the string `"zygote"`.

That means `app_process` is changed to zygote process using the `set_process_name()` function. If it is true, everything is OK. But I don't know what the fact is.

Anyone make me sure of what is first.

***Try to browse android code in :***

http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/

Comment: May be this is helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153166/understanding-android-zygote-and-dalvikvm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dalvik is shipped on Android as a loadable library. `app_process` links with that library, and uses it. As such `app_process` starts a Dalvik VM within its own process.

The Zygote is just a special case of this.

So, to more directly answer your question: During a typical start-up, the first Dalvik VM to run is one that is spawned within an `app_process` process, and it is passed arguments which cause it to become the Zygote process of the running system.

Comment: As you said, Having some elements of DVM app_process become Zygote process with passed arguments from init process as description in init.rc file. Right?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean, but I think the answer is "yes".

Comment: OK. let me make you sure.
init.rc file is a description of to-do list of Init process.
When init process call app_process, it give some arguments about Zygote to app_process.
A string, "zygote", is one of those arguments.
So using it, app_process change its name to "zygote". You meant that as I understood.
Anyway, I really thank you for help.