# OpenSSL library not creating SO file

Tags: android, ssl, android-ndk, openssl

Hi i am trying to build  the libcrypto.so and libssl.so file for use with one of our Android NDK projects using  this guide below

https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android

At the end of the process it seems to spit on libcrypto.a and libssl.a files instead?

Here are the commands i executed

```
sudo ./config shared no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-comp no-hw no-engine --openssldir=/Users/jon/ssl/$ANDROID_API/ \ --with-fipsdir=/Users/jon/ssl/$ANDROID_API/ --with-fipslibdir=/Users/jon/ssl/$ANDROID_API/lib/

make depend

make all

sudo -E make install CC=$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc RANLIB=$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib
```

what am i missing?

Comment: Using OpenSSL's shared objects will probably produce incorrect results on Android due to Zygote. Zygote will load Android's [old, downlevel] version of OpenSSL, so your libraries will not be loaded. See, for example, [Understanding Android: Zygote and DalvikVM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9153166/608639). You should use `libcrypto.a` and `libssl.a` instead. That's detailed under [Android | Wrapper Shared Objects](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android#Wrapper_Shared_Objects).

Comment: Ok so I should create a wrapper instead? As described in the open ssl link?