# What is the Difference between a Device Policy Controller (DCP) app and a System App?

Tags: android, mobility

Is there any difference in the privileges of an Android DPC application and a system application? Will a system application be able to perform all the functions that a DPC can perform such as setting the device to Single Use Mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is *no-such* difference in privileges as far as the [Android system](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/index.html) is concerned.

If you look at the [Android Platform Architecture](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/index.html), you will find that the even a *normal* user app have the same access to all the system resources as a *system* app.

> Apps included with the platform have no special status among the apps the user chooses to install. So a third-party app can become the user's default web browser, SMS messenger, or even the default keyboard (some exceptions apply, such as the system's Settings app).

You can read about more [differences in system and user app here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17871/what-are-the-differences-between-a-system-app-and-user-app).

Also, another *interesting* point to note is that on a production device there are only 3-processes that run as `root`, the [Zygote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153166/understanding-android-zygote-and-dalvikvm), the [app_process](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0419ab9e4a7761e2aac7e1bec73057b3beba97ec/cmds/app_process/app_main.cpp) and the [adbd](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) (though it doesn't allow root access directly using `adb`). That means, all other apps run under their own `user_id` with different permissions and since Android doesn't differentiate between apps, two apps having same permissions are allowed same privileges and access to resources, regardless of the fact whether it is a system app or a user app.

Now, to answer your question, if a *system* app has the same privileges as the *DPC* app, then yes the app would be able to perform the given task (like setting the device to Single Use Mode) same as the *DPC* without any problem.

As a side note, if you are planning to create a *DPC* for you organisation, using the [DPC SUpport Library](https://developers.google.com/android/work/dpc/build-dpc#download_the_library) is better than creating and shipping a system app.

P.S. To change a System setting your app would need the [WRITE_SETTINGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_SETTINGS) permission.